# Haskell: own Set data type instance of Show doesn't work

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have implemented the data type SetList to have a distinct set.

this is my code:

```
data SetList a = Set [a]

empty = Set []

member x (Set xs) = x `elem` xs 

insert x a@(Set xs)
  | member x a = a
  | otherwise = Set (x : xs)

remove x a@(Set xs) = case span (/= x) xs of
  (_, []) -> a
  (first, _ : last) -> Set $ first ++ last

instance Show a => Show (SetList a) where
 show (Set xs) = "{" ++ foldr func "}" xs
  where 
   func x y  = show x ++ ", " ++ y
```

I have to write an instance of Show using a version of fold, but i have struggles with that.
The last section is my approach, but it doesn't really work.

This is what i get and what it should look like:
`ghci> tests *** show1: ERROR; expected '{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}', but found '{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, }'`

The problem is obviously the ',' at the back. I managed to do it without fold, but the exercise states I have to use a version of fold

Comment: `DList` is not a constructor of the `SetList` type.

Comment: oh, i renamed the Set to post it here, forgot that; edited that, thank you!

Comment: A classmate(?) posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74703516/1126841)

Comment: @chepner yes, thank you, thats actually a class mate!